# C++20 views::join goes into an infinite loop on generated nested ranges::single_view

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'm playing with C++20 ranges with GCC implementations (v10.2 & v11).

To test the behavior of [`std::views::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view), I tried to generate a nested view using `single` and then I *flat* it using `join`.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto data = std::views::single(1);
  auto v =
      data
      | std::views::transform([](const auto &s) { return std::views::single(s); })
      | std::views::join
      ;

  for (auto &&x : v) { // Infinite loop + segfault
    std::cout << x << '\n';
  }
}
```

[[in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6zfjbePzj)]

I expected to find one iterator of the *for* loop with the initial value (1).
But no... It goes into an infinite loop which segfaults since I use the value.

If I replace the nested `std::views::single` with `std::views::iota(a,b)` or `std::views::empty<int>`, the behavior is perfectly OK.

Do you have an idea if this is the correct expected behavior (and why)?

**edit**

`std::ranges::next(v.begin()) == v.end()` must be true.

This was a bug in GCC 10.3 and 11.1 .
It has been fixed in GCC trunk and 11.1.1 .

Comment: NB: it could be related to the following remark in cppreference: *The inner range type (ranges::range_reference_t<V>) cannot be a container type (but can be reference to container)* even if usually it leads to a compiler error not a abnormal behavior.

Comment: Compile fine with [range-v3](https://godbolt.org/z/WE7na3zMK).

Comment: `std::next(v.begin()) != v.end()` - interesting ...

Comment: Bug. Filed https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100290

Comment: Ok; I was suspecting it was a bug. Thx. I will follow it.