# joining std::ranges::single_views unexpected results

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I'm trying to understand some basic constructions with `std::ranges` like the Pythagorean triples examples of [Niebler's blog](https://ericniebler.com/2018/12/05/standard-ranges/). However, when I try the following baby example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template<class R, typename Fun>
auto for_each(R&& r, Fun f) {
    return std::forward<R>(r) | std::views::transform(std::move(f)) | std::views::join;
}

int main() {
    auto ints = for_each(std::views::iota(0,9), [](int i) {
            return std::ranges::single_view<int>{i};
            });

    for (auto k : ints | std::views::take(3)) {
        std::cout << k << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints gibberish. A random output is

```
0 731868824 0
```

This program simply takes a `std::views::iota` that would generate the numbers 0 through 8, and then for each integer `i` in this view it generates a `std::ranges::single_view` that has only the integer `i` in it. The implementation of `for_each` there should simply concatenate all those single views and then flatten them back, obtaining the original sequence of numbers 0 through 8.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282639 Your code prints `0 1 2` on GCC trunk. https://godbolt.org/z/81K8fcW8P

Comment: ohh nice thanks! I was about to post that if I change `single_view` for another like a `iota_view` it works fine. Tough to learn like this, been banging by head against this the whole afternoon